# Command-line client for gpm daemon?

Tags: linux, command-line, mouse, copy-paste

I want to put output of some command in the gpm "clipboard", like:

```
echo "hello" | some-fancy-gpm-client
```

to be able to then "right-click" and paste it to terminal.

Is there some program for that? Maybe some term escape codes? Or at least, where could I find protocol used by gpm, so that I could maybe write such a client by myself?

Thanks in advance.